# Why is this [二番目]{に・ばん・め} counter used for a person?

Tags: counters

Here is a small passage from my Japanese Bible, where a king is summoning his servants.

> さて、彼は...帰って来ると、...[僕]{しもべ}を呼んで来させ、...。 最初の者が...。***二番目***の者が来て...

Why is it referring to the second servant as `二番目の者` instead of the more intuitive (at least to me) `二人目`?  Is this derogatory somehow, or is it essentially relating `[僕]{しもべ}` to a `番人`, and `番人` are simply counted with `～番`?

Are there other acceptable times to count people this way?

Comment: Doesn't “二番目” simply mean “the second”?  Or do you mean to ask “二つ目” (this second object)?

Comment: Here is a related article that might be useful: [related article](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/13009/%E3%80%8C%E4%BA%8C%E7%95%AA%E3%80%8D-vs-%E3%80%8C%E4%BA%8C%E7%95%AA%E7%9B%AE%E3%80%8D-confusion)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think 「二番目」 just means "second" as "second in order" which is not really a counter of people but a way of expressing order, including order of people. The king first calls a servant and then calls the second (in order servant).

Quickly looking in the internet, I found some other examples of applying 「二番目」 to people:

> **二番目の女**から本命彼女になる方法 ([link](http://slism.net/love/how-to-become-first-woman.html))
>
> **二番目の男**でもいい、と告白されました。 ([link](http://www.ca-girlstalk.jp/talk/detail/282748))
>
> **二番目の子**が生まれてから、上の子と接する時間が少なくなった私。([link](http://www.shimajiro.co.jp/kosodate/ikuji/resistance/hahakodomo/kawaii/post_470.shtml))