# Superlatives: How do I say "X is the nth most [adjective]"?

Tags: grammar, translation

Trying to say "LAX is the 4th busiest airport in the world" and that "Narita is the 5th".

Couldn't find any info online about superlatives with ranking so if there's some site detailing this grammar, I'd love to see it too!

Comment: See also: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/13027/9831

Comment: I find the most suitable expression for this case is the 第１, 第２ style which seems to be not discussed in those threads. How learners can meet other possibilities from finished threads?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Superlatives: How do I say “X is the nth most [adjective]”?

'The most' is commonly expressed as 最も{もっとも}, or more plainly 一番{いちばん}: 最も簡単{かんたん}な方法{ほうほう}, 日本で一番、高い{たかい}山{やま}は富士山{ふじさん}です. Also we have expressions like 最高{さいこう} (the highest), 最大{さいだい} (the biggest), etc: 最高記録 (the best record).

The second is 二番目{にばんめ}: クラスで二番目に背{せ}が高い.

> Trying to say "LAX is the 4th busiest airport in the world"

LAX（ロサンゼルス空港）は世界で**四番目に** 繁華{はんか}な空港｛くうこう｝です. I think this 繁華な is the word for it, meaning the busiest/the most bustling airport. Or also you can say something like LAXは世界で**第４の**利用者数{りようしゃすう}を誇る{ほこる}空港です, meaning the airport is proud to have the 4th biggest number of users in the world.

> and that "Narita is the 5th".

次｛つ｝いで成田｛なりた｝は世界で**第５の**空港です。(Narita comes next and is the fifth airport in the world.)

I feel the style of 第４, 第５ is slightly more nice and businesslike.